# Connect to two VPNs in series

Tags: vpn

I connect my MacBook to a headless server at work via a Cisco AnyConnect VPN and ssh. Let's call it UbuntuServer. Now I need to get some data from a collaborator who's ftp server is behind a FortiClient VPN. Let's call their server RemoteFTP. On UbuntuServer I downloaded `openfortivpn` to connect to the network for RemoteFTP, but having UbuntuServer connect to RemoteFTP disconnects my home Macbook from UbuntuServer. How can I connect to RemoteFTP without losing my initial connection?

Comment: You don't due to the configuration of the RemoteFTP VPN.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was at https://github.com/adrienverge/openfortivpn/issues/371. I needed to set up the second VPN link without any routes, and then manually add a route just for the server I wanted to connect to.

```
sudo openfortivpn remoteFTP:443 --username=pgcudahy --no-routes --no-dns
```

For the next step I needed to use the IP address of remoteFTP. Let's call it `123.456.789.012`

```
route add 123.456.789.012 dev ppp0
```

Now I can use

```
ssh pgcudahy@123.456.789.012
```

And now I can access the (double) remote files